# How do you connect paintEvent to a slot?

Tags: c++, qt

Just like the title says I want to connect `paintEvent` to a slot, so that it can be triggered by a timer, how do I do this? I can provide any more information you guys need, I'm very new to QT though, so keep that in mind.

EDIT: So I tried it in a little test program and it doesn't appear to be updating. Unless I've misunderstood how `paintEvent` works, I don't know what's wrong. This should move a black point (10x10 pixels) across the screen from the upper left corner to the bottom right.

Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();
    QTimer *timer;

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Here's the implementation file:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "windows.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));

    timer->start(1000);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen pointPen(Qt::black);
    pointPen.setWidth(10);
    painter.setPen(pointPen);
    QPoint test;

    static unsigned int coord;

    coord = 10;

    test.setX(coord);
    test.setY(coord);

    painter.drawPoint(test);

    coord += 10;
```

}

Here's the client code:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You're re-setting coord to 10 each time before painting, so the paint will happen, but always at (10, 10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot connect to `paintEvent` directly, since it is not a slot. Instead, connect your timer signal to `repaint` (to trigger an immediate repaint) or `update` (the preferred method, since it consolidates multiple repaint requests to avoid flicker).

**EDIT**

There's some quirkiness regarding updating a `QDialog` (see [this thread on the Qt forums](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-7188)) -- apparently, due to a bug in Qt versions 4.6 and below (and possibly in later versions, as well).

I would refrain from overriding `paintEvent` on a `QDialog`. Instead, create a custom `QWidget` (which you can insert as a child into your dialog) and perform your rendering there.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example ....

in widget.h file ...

```
class Widget:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QPainter    painter;
    QTimer      timer;
public:
    Widget();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};
```

in widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    connect(&timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(update()));
    timer.start(200);
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    painter.begin(this);
    painter.drawRect(0,0,100,rand()%200);
    painter.end();
}
```

in main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```